# plotting from cell array of different lengths

Tags: matlab, plot

this might come as an eco in this forum but I couldn't find a solution that I could apply to my problem. I have a cell of res_A1 of size (1x500) and in each cell there is a vector (1xlength) where length varies. I would like to plot in the same graph every vector or maybe a handful of them. All lines can be in the same color. I have tried following but the graph make no sense

```
data=res_A1(1,:,end);
plot(cell2mat(data)');
```

Also I would like to plot the average of the 500 vectors, preferably this should be in the same graph in another color. Is there a nice way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cat` to combine the vectors along the first dimension. Then you can pass the transpose of this matrix to `plot` and each column will be plotted as it's own plot.

```
plot(cat(1, data{:}).');
```

If we create some example data, this will yield.

```
data = arrayfun(@(x)rand(1,10), ones(1, 5), 'uni', 0);
plot(cat(1, data{:}).');
```

[image]

If you want specific ones (i.e. `[1 3 5]`), you can replace `:` above with the indices of the ones you want.

```
plot(cat(1, data{[1 3 5]}).');
```

[image]

If you want to plot the average, simply use `mean` on the result of the call to `cat`.

```
avg = mean(cat(1, data{:}), 1);
plot(avg);
```

[image]

And if you wanted it in the same plot:

```
alldata = cat(1, data{:});
avg = mean(alldata, 1);

% Plot all of the curves
plot(alldata.');

hold on

% Plot the average curve
plot(avg, 'LineWidth', 3, 'Color', [0.5 0.5 0.5], 'LineStyle', '--')
```

[image]

**Update**

If your data is all different lengths, You have two options, you could plot everything with a loop.

```
hax = axes;
hold(hax, 'on');

for k = 1:numel(data)
    plot(data{k}, 'Parent', hax);
end
```

Or you could still try to combine everything into one matrix, padding with `NaN` values.

```
% Find the longest vector length
maxlength = max(cellfun(@(x)numel(x), data));

alldata = nan(maxlength, numel(data));

for k = 1:numel(data)
    alldata(1:numel(data{k}),k) = data{k};
end
```

Then you can plot this and take the mean using `nanmean`.

```
plot(alldata);

avg = nanmean(alldata, 2);
```

Comment: This works perfect with the sample data. But my data are of different length so I get the message 'Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.'

Comment: @Orongo updated with an example of how to deal with different length vectors.